# PhpStorm with Yii2 dynamic field warning

Tags: yii, phpstorm

I used PhpStorm and Yii2 framework to develop the blog website.

I got a warning when I put this code on. I don't know which problem cause these warning.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your question so code will be in text form, what is your expected result, and what is the real result.

Comment: You can add PHPDoc comment with type hint into your `<?php ...?>` section in that file: e.g. `/** @var MyModelClass $model */`. https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Comment: Thank you so  much brother,i got

Answer (score 0):

Well .. for pure PHP templates it's pretty simple: just add PHPDoc with type hint into `<?php ... ?>` section of this view/template file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
/** @var MyModelClass $model */
?>
```

More on PHPDoc and `@var` tag syntax in particular: https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Comment: Thank you so much and i modified the configuration in preference also find inspection item and search 'undefined field' then i gave the first item a uncheck ,so,there you go buddy.Any warnings disappeared

Comment: Disabling inspection is a wrong way (it is useful as it helps wringing code that uses existing methods and not misspelled one etc). But if you wish doing it that way -- you are welcome .. as long as code works it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: Okay,got it in my heart.Thanks.